# What is a good connecting word for "First: the list of properties, ____ A, B, C, ..."?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, ellipsis, run-on-sentences

I am listing some features for a software system and in one of the list items, I wrote:

> First: the list of properties, which are parameters required by the framework.

Now, I want to list these parameters, I can't use ***such as***, because I want to list all of them and *such as* indicates some of them, and I can't use ***which are*** because I already used *which*. So, what is the correct word here?

I want to say something like:

> First: the list of properties, which are parameters required by the framework. and they are ...

I think can't use ***and*** directly after the ellipses,
which is what I know in grammar, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: You can use "the list of properties, which are A, B, C, D, and E" (where "parameters required by the framework" is A). You can also simply use a colon: "First, the list of properties: A, B, C, D, and E".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't find a good coordinating conjunction, try a semi-colon:

> First: the list of properties, which are parameters required by the framework; **these are** A, B, C, and D.